# tidyverse package will not load

Tags: rstudio, package

I am running the latest version of Rstudio (1.1.453) on Mac. Since installing the latest version of R-Studio, I can no longer get tidyverse package to load. Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

I get the following error message.

```
> library("tidyverse", lib.loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library")
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘dplyr’
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing it with dependencies:`install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = TRUE)`

I had a similar issue and if this doesn't fix it, try to install `dplyr` manually: `install.packages("dplyr")`